# Automapper: Convert an int to a string

Tags: c#, string, int, type-conversion, automapper

I am currently using AutoMapper in my c# MVC project and have come across an issue converting from a integer to a string.

I have two classes:

```
public class Job
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set }
    public int JobPriority { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityPriority EntityPriority { get; set; }
}

public class JobViewModel
{
    public string JobNumberFull { get; set; }
{
```

Using Automapper I would like to join all three properties in the Job class to form a string which will then be mapped to JobNumberFull in the JobViewModel class.:

Prefix-JobNumber-Year

To start I have kept things simple and not concatenated the fields into a string, I have just tried to take JobNumber (int) and map it to JobNumberFull (string) as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<int, string>().ConvertUsing(Convert.ToString);
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.JobPriorityId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.EntityPriority.EntityPriorityID))
    .ForMember(d => d.JobPriorityLevel, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.EntityPriority.PriorityLevel))
    .ForMember(d => d.JobNumberFull, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.JobNumberYear));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var jobsList = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.OperationID == operationId).Project().To<JobViewModel>().ToList();
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
Type 'System.String' does not have a default constructor
```

I know this is to do with

```
Convert.ToString
```

but I'm not sure what to do about it! I can do Convert.ToInt32 when going from a string to an int and it works like a treat. Do I need to create a custom type converter?

How would I go about getting the string prefix-jobnumber-year?

All help much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help of Jeremy and the AutoMapper website I have managed to get this working here is my solution, please feel free to comment if you think there is a more elegant solution:

```
public class Job 
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int JobPriority { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityPriority EntityPriority { get; set; }
}

public class JobViewModel 
{
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string JobNumberFull { get; set; }
}

public enum EntityPriority 
{
  Normal = 0,
  High
}

public interface IValueResolver
{
   ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source);
}

public class JobNumberConverter : ValueResolver<Job, string>
{
    protected override string ResolveCore(Job source)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", source.Prefix, source.JobNumber, source.Year);
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobViewModel>()
        .ForMember(jvm => jvm.JobNumberFull, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<JobNumberConverter>());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    List<Job> jobs = new List<Job>();

    Job j = new Job()
    {
        JobNumber = 1,
        Prefix = "prefix",
        Year = 2013,
        EntityPriority = EntityPriority.High,
        JobPriority = 2
    };

    Job j2 = new Job()
    {
        JobNumber = 2,
        Prefix = "prefix",
        Year = 2013,
        EntityPriority = EntityPriority.High,
        JobPriority = 2
    };

    Job j3 = new Job()
    {
        JobNumber = 3,
        Prefix = "prefix",
        Year = 2013,
        EntityPriority = EntityPriority.High,
        JobPriority = 2
    };

    jobs.Add(j);
    jobs.Add(j2);
    jobs.Add(j3);

    var jobViewModels = jobs.Select(job => Mapper.Map<JobViewModel>(job));

    return View();

}
```

Comment: It's much simpler if you don't try to simplify so much and just specify a conversion function for Job to JobViewModel. [Please read about the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and avoid it for your next question. :)

Comment: One other thing to note - projection actually creates a LINQ query to feed to EF. With Resolvers or ConvertUsing, those aren't used in the LINQ query, only MapFrom is. A quick fix is to simply do ToString(). In your JobNumberFull, use MapFrom - but use string concatenation instead of string.Format (EF doesn't know string.Format). This will create a custom SQL query for you instead!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use the `ResolveUsing` method to solve it.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.JobNumberFull,
    exp =>
    exp.ResolveUsing(j => string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", j.Prefix, j.JobNumber, j.Year)));
```

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer as it provides an elegant inline usage to what I wanted to achieve. I have left the update on my original question as this shows how to write a reuseable value converter.

Comment: Thanks to all in helping me achieve a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a custom conversion function for the conversion from Job to JobViewModel.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Job, JobViewModel>().ConvertUsing(
  job => new JobViewModel {
    JobNumberFull = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                      job.Prefix, job.JobNumber, Job.Year)
  });
```

To convert a Job to JobViewModel, use the Map function.

```
var jobViewModel = Mapper.Map<JobViewModel>(job);
```

To convert a list of Jobs to JobViewModels, use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method.

```
var jobViewModels = jobs.Select(job => Mapper.Map<JobViewModel>(job));
```

Comment: Jeremy thanks for your response, this works in that I don't get an error but it is not populating the fields, they are all null. I have added back in my .ForMember lines for a couple of other fields I'm flattening and they are also null once the projection has been completed.

Comment: Are you trying to create a JobViewModel from a Job or a Job from a JobViewModel?

Comment: Oh, and what is the ListJobsViewModel type in Line 2 of the second code block in your question?

Comment: I'm trying to create a JobViewModel from a Job. I am selecting many jobs from the database, the jobs table has lots of unrequired fields for the data I need to display (I shortened my job class above) so I have created a JobViewModel to just expose the data I require to be displayed.

Comment: I updated my answer with the full test code I'm using. It outputs prefix-1-2013 to the console.

Comment: I tried out your code and I got it to work but my code fails on the projection: var jobsList = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.OperationID == operationId).Project().To<JobViewModel>().ToList();

Comment: So how would I go about converting a list of class Job and converting this to a list of JobViewModel so that I can then call Mapper.Map<JobViewModel>(j)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I feel that I am very close to getting this working! The above code for doing it on multiple records is working and it now formats the string correctly however all the other fields are not being filled out, they are null or 0.